# Compare two UTC dates with date-fns

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, timezone, date-fns

I'm trying to compare two dates in UTC format with ***date-fns***, but I'm not getting it. The two values ​​look the same, but the **isEquals()** function returns false for comparison.

The purpose of the code below is to search for the schedules that are marked and check if they fit the times of the array **range**, if there is a compatible schedule, it returns the object by inserting it in the constant date

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { utcToZonedTime } from 'date-fns-tz';
import {
  format,
  setHours,
  setMinutes,
  setSeconds,
  isBefore,
  isEqual,
  parseISO,
} from 'date-fns';
import enUS from 'date-fns/locale/en-US';

import api from '~/services/api';

const range = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadSchedule() {
      const response = await api.get('schedule', {
        params: { date },
      });

      const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

      const data = range.map((hour) => {
        const checkDate = setSeconds(setMinutes(setHours(date, hour), 0), 0);
        const compareDate = utcToZonedTime(checkDate, timezone);

        return {
          time: `${hour}:00h`,
          past: isBefore(compareDate, new Date()),
          appointment: response.data.find((appoint) =>
            isEqual(parseISO(appoint.date), compareDate)
          ),
        };
      });

      setSchedule(data);
    }

    loadSchedule();
  }, [date]);

}
```

I made a test code to print the results on the *Reactotron* and below are the printed values:

```
console.tron.log(`${isEqual(parseISO(response.data[1].date), 
                   compareDate)}\n
                   ${parseISO(response.data[1].date)}\n${compareDate}`);
```

Result:

```
false
Wed Jun 10 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
Wed Jun 10 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
```

Actual values ​​for each of the dates:

```
console.tron.log(`${response.data[1].date}\n${compareDate}`);
```

```
2020-06-10T22:00:00.000Z
Wed Jun 10 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
```

But if I print only the value of the compareDate variable, it changes the format:

```
console.tron.log(compareDate);
```

```
2020-06-10T21:00:00.002Z
```

Comment: Does one value have non-zero milliseconds?  Log `.toISOString()` on the dates to check.

Comment: I am using the partner because of the time zone. I tried using .toISOString (), but the following error occurred: 

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): response.data[1].date.toISOString is not a function**

The test wen like this:



```console.tron.log(${parseISO(response.data[1].date)}\n${response.data[1].date.toISOString()}`);```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`date-fns`'s `isEqual()` function also takes into consideration the milliseconds value, as questioned in the comments.

This information can also be found on [date-fns isEqual() docs](https://date-fns.org/docs/isEqual), in the example:

```
// Are 2 July 2014 06:30:45.000 and 2 July 2014 06:30:45.500 equal?

var result = isEqual(
  new Date(2014, 6, 2, 6, 30, 45, 0),
  new Date(2014, 6, 2, 6, 30, 45, 500)
)
// it returns false`
```

You should import `setMilliseconds()` from `date-fns` and also use it in the line where you set `checkDate` value.